# mongoose unique:false not working for postal code

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So I'm using mongodb/mongoose and am trying to submit a form that only checks for a unique email, but for some reason, it's also checking for a unique postal code and I'm not sure why. All the other information works if I have duplicates like first name, last name etc. You can try for yourself and submit the same info twice but with different email and it won't work unless you also have a different postal code It's being stored on mlab
Here's a link to the website on heroku https://aqueous-basin-28448.herokuapp.com/Join.html

ERROR MESSAGE: ERROR MESSAGE WriteError({"code":11000,"index":0,"errmsg":"E11000 duplicate key error index: yorkdale.users.$postalCode_1 dup key: { : \"M6
A 1T8\" }","op":

//mongo.js file

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const nameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

firstName:{
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'First Name is required'],
     unique: false
},
lastName:{
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Last Name is required'],
    unique: false
},
Address:{
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Address is required'],
    unique: false
},
postalCode:{
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Postal Code is required'],
    unique: false
},
Email:{
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Email is required'],
    unique: true
}
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', nameSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

//FORM

```
 <form action = "/join" method = "post">
                <div class = "form-group">
                     <input class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name" required value="" />
                </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" id="lastName" name="lastName" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" id="Address" name="Address" type="text" placeholder="Address" required />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" id="postalCode" name="postalCode" type="text" placeholder="Postal Code" required />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" id="Email" name="Email" type="text" placeholder="Email" required />
                </div>
                 <div class="row">
                    <div class="buttonContainer">
                        <button type="submit" id = "button" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button><br/><br />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

//Node.js post

```
app.post('/join', function(req,res){
    var myData = new User(req.body);
    myData.save().then(item => {
       res.send("Information saved to database");
    }).catch(err => {
       res.status(400).send("Error! Unable to save to database. Email already used! Please go back and try again");
    });
});
```

Comment: A good start is to provide us with the real error thrown by Mongoose. Put a `console.log(err)` in the `catch` callback and share it.

Comment: ERROR MESSAGE WriteError({"code":11000,"index":0,"errmsg":"E11000 duplicate key error index: yorkdale.users.$postalCode_1 dup key: { : \"M6
A 1T8\" }","op":

Comment: Try running in the mongo shell `db.users.dropIndex('postalCode_1')`